# ¿Cómo Extraer parte fija y decimal de un Double en Java?

Tags: java

Funciones para extraer la parte entera y la parte decimal de un numero almacenado en un Doble en Java.

Tengo lo siguiente realizado:

```
double number = 31.54;

long iPart = (long) number;
double fPart = number - iPart;

System.out.println("Integer part = " + iPart);
System.out.println("Fractional part = " + fPart);
```

Su salida es:

```
 I/System.out: Integer part = 31
 I/System.out: Fractional part = 0.5399999999999991
```

Lo que devería devolver

```
I/System.out: Integer part = 31     
I/System.out: Fractional part = 0.54
I/System.out: Fractional partToInt = 54
```

Comment: Tienes un problema de precisión de parte del Double, si necesitas algo más preciso utiliza BigDecimal https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html ya que Double o Float no son precisos.

Comment: @Ajeno: Si puedes agregar esto como respuesta junto con algún ejemplo usando `BigDecimal`, eso sería ideal, ya que esta es la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema del Double es su precisión, por que le interesa más el espacio en memoría (8 bytes) que la precisión.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precisi%C3%B3n_simple_en_coma_flotante

Tiene sus usos cuando no importa tanto la diferencia, pero para cálculos aritméticos como pudieran ser estados de cuenta, etc simplemente no funcionan, lo que te recomiendo es usar BigDecimal.

En está página te explican a más detalle por que no utilizarlo.
http://www.javamexico.org/blogs/luxspes/por_que_usar_bigdecimal_y_no_double_para_calculos_aritmeticos_financieros

Ahora como lo utilizarías sería algo así:

Para no perder precisión recomiendo el constructor con String

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("31.54");
long iPart = number.longValue();
BigDecimal fraccion = number.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);

System.out.println("Integer part = " + iPart);
System.out.println("Fractional part = " + fraccion);
```

Solo algo por aclarar el objeto BigDecimal son siempre inmutables como lo son los String, por lo que si vas a trabajar con un objeto siempre debes asignar su valor para cambiar de objeto. Como en donde se le hizo el remainder no alteré el objeto number, debí asígnarlo a una variable nueva, aunque se puede utilizar la misma casí no es recomendable.

Answer (score 3):

Si se trata de un número decimal que puede expresarse sin exponente:

❍ *Código*:

```
double number;
number = 31.54;

String str = String.valueOf(number);

int intNumber = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.indexOf('.')));
float decNumbert = Float.parseFloat(str.substring(str.indexOf('.')));
int decNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.indexOf('.') + 1));

System.out.println(intNumber);
System.out.println(decNumbert);
System.out.println(decNumberInt);
```

❍ *Salida*:

```
31
0.54
54
```

Comment: veo que si se computa en forma de cadena, no se altera el valor, ya que lo que yo hago obtengo 0.539999999999....

Answer (score 2):

Después de la recomendación de @Ajeno y investigando sobre `BigDecimal` dejo el ejemplo de testeo final:

```
    double number = 31.54;
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(number));
    BigDecimal iPart = new BigDecimal(bd.toBigInteger());
    BigDecimal fPart = bd.remainder( BigDecimal.ONE );
    BigDecimal fPartToInt = bd.subtract(bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR)).movePointRight(bd.scale());

    System.out.println("Integer part = " + iPart);
    System.out.println("Fractional part = " + fPart);
    System.out.println("Fractional part Int = " + fPartToInt);
```

Salida

```
I/System.out: Integer part = 31
I/System.out: Fractional part = 0.54
I/System.out: Fractional part Int = 54
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double number = 31.54;
int integerPart = (int) number;
String str = String.format("%.2f", fractinalPart);

System.out.println("Integer part = " + integerPart);
System.out.println("Fractional part = " + str);

Integer part = 31
Fractional part = 0.54
```

Comment: Hola Willy, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y pueden resultar confusas para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir una descripción de lo que  hace el código y cómo resuelve el problema expuesto en la pregunta. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).