# Numero flotante - Seperar numero entero de decimal JAVA 8

Tags: java, java-8

Tengo que crear un método main que permita mostrar la parte entera y separado la parte decimal de un tipo de dato float

Recien estoy empezando

Este es el codigo

float numeroFloat = 123.1f;

```
    int parteEntera= 123;

    int parteDecimal = (int) 1f;


    System.out.println("La parte entera es "+parteEntera+" La parte decimal es "+parteDecimal);
```

Pero no se si es correcto entonces me queda la duda como seria:

```
   float numeroFloat = 123.1f;

    int parteEntera= ???;

    int parteDecimal = ????;


    System.out.println("La parte entera es "+parteEntera+" La parte decimal es "+parteDecimal);\
```

Perdonen ya que recién estoy empezando

Comment: Hola amigo, esto posiblemente te ayude https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36038/c%C3%B3mo-extraer-parte-fija-y-decimal-de-un-double-en-java

Comment: @JuanchiCordero si te ayudó la respuesta de Ricardo, considera aceptarla presionando la marca de verificación a la izquierda (✅) de la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución es pasar tu float a un String y luego dividirlo por el punto, así:

```
float numeroFloat = 123.1f;
    String s =String.valueOf(numeroFloat);
    String[] floats = s.split("\\.");
    System.out.println("La parte entera es "+floats[0]+" La parte decimal es "+floats[1]);
```